# How to convert a AChartEngine chart to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, achartengine

I want to convert a line graph I made with AChartEngine lib to bitmap.How should I do?I didn't found on the net anything that can help.
Is the toBitmap() method suitable?if yes then how to use it?

**Update**:
I used this method :

```
 public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {  
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
v.layout( 0,0,800,600);
v.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
v.buildDrawingCache();
v.getDrawingCache();
 Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(800,600, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
return bmp; }
```

and saved the result in a png file but all I got is an empty file !

Answer (score 0):

toBitmap() seems to always return null.

Try this:

```
            //Get the graphical view 
            GraphicalView v = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, 
                            buildDataset(titles, x, values), renderer); 

           //Enable the cache 
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); 

            //Set the layout manually to 800*600 
            v.layout(0, 0, 800, 600); 

            //Set the quality to high 
            v.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH); 

            //Build the cache, get the bitmap and close the cache 
            v.buildDrawingCache(true); 
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache()); 
            v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late but this is what I did to create a JPG (via Bitmap) from a GraphicalView:

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( 600, 1000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
graphicalView.draw( canvas );

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( filename );
bmp.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 97, out );
out.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG is more efficient for charts. I hacked AChartEngine to output SVG, for the specific kind of charts we are using. The hack is easy to extend to other charts. If this interests anyone, respond to this answer and I'll put what I did in a Gist.